# How can I customize the ExceptionMessage thrown by Apex Class?

Tags: visualforce, exception, controller-extension

I am getting the following message on my VF page.

**common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException:** Unable to Parse Date Value

I wish to suppress the first part of the message which is **common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException**

In my controller extension class, there is a method that is throwing an exception. This is the set method.

```
public void setCloseDate(Date closeDT)
{
  try{
  Date.parse(String.valueOf(closeDT));
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      throw new clException('Unable to Parse Date Value');
  }


  if(closeDT > Date.newInstance(2015, 1, 1))
  {
       closeDate = closeDT;
  }
  else
  {
     //ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR ,'Please enter a valid date!'));
     throw new clException('Invalid Value - Close Date!');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
Date.parse(String.valueOf(closeDT))
```

is a strange piece of code because you are turning a `Date` into a `String` and then parsing it back into a `Date`. In most locales it will always fail because `Date.parse` expects the date format that `Date.format` produces not the one that `String.valueOf` produces. And if you did change it you would have something that always works.

You need a method that takes a string and then tries to parse that if your aim is to check that the string is a correctly formatted date.

A good way to turn exceptions into messages in a page is to convert the message string part of the exception into and `ApexPages.Message` that is then presented in an `apex:pageMessages` tag with no mention of the exception type:

```
try {
    // Call code that can throw a TypeException
} catch (TypeException) {
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why not just `ApexPages.addMessages(e)`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Good point and worth trying. I've used that for DmlExceptions where it gives the best results, just never tried it with simple exceptions like this. (Not the real reason I didn't do that, but the question is "How can I customize..." and creating the message yourself lets you customize it completely.)

Comment: Right, that makes more sense in the context of the OP. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianLarson and Keith: my experience (and it was a while ago) was that if the VF controller try block did DML and a Validation error ensued and you then caught the error and generated an `Apexpages.Message`, that the page would show two messages, one placed implictly by VF from the VR and a second, duplicate one you did explicitly in the catch block. I ended up putting in a handler to detect this before constructing a `ApexPages.Message`, if any.

Comment: @cropredy I've code that does a catch of DmlException and Adrian's ApexPages.addMessages and that seems to avoid the duplicate errors but maybe the ApexPages.addMessages is redundant in that case (as it is filtered as a duplicate).

Comment: could be a version issue; I should revisit this

Comment: @cropredy Could also be my bad memory of what and why...